# Changer le planning, changer le plan ou changer le programme?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> J’hésite à te voir car la dernière fois que nous nous sommes vus, tu as changé brutalement le **planning** de notre rencontre amicale au dernier moment: nous devions nous rendre chez toi au sortir du restaurant mais nous en sommes restés là, sous prétexte que la fatigue te gagnait. À mon sens, tu m’as laissé en plan et c’est fort impoli.

> J’hésite à te voir car la dernière fois que nous nous sommes vus, tu as changé brutalement le **programme** de notre rencontre amicale au dernier moment: nous devions sortir chez toi après le souper au restaurant mais nous en sommes restés là, prétextant que la fatigue te gagnait. À mon sens, tu m’as laissé en plan et c’est fort impoli.

> J’hésite à te voir car la dernière fois que nous nous sommes vus, tu as changé brutalement le **plan** de notre rencontre amicale au dernier moment: on devait sortir chez toi après le souper au restaurant mais nous en sommes restés là, sous prétexte que la fatigue te gagnait. À mon sens, tu m’as laissé en plan et c’est fort impoli.

Je serais heureux que vous me présentiez à votre convenance d’autres façons plus simples de rendre cette idée, d’énoncer différemment la phrase concernée en misant sur la concision, quitte à la repenser du tout au tout. À noter qu’il ne s’agit point d’une injonction mais d’un souhait et précisons qu’en l’occurence je navigue dans le site complet de *French Stack Exchange*, je n’ai donc pas accès au chat intitulé *Chez Cossette* (hélas cette fonctionnalité est inexistante dans l’application mobile, ce serait d’ailleurs bien qu’un jour elle en devienne une partie constitutive) . La décision de m’offrir ou non une reformulation de la phrase concernée vous appartient et au demeurant, je vous prie de bien vouloir vous abstenir de me rappeler les formalités de *Stack Exchange*: elles sont très fraîches dans ma mémoire.

Comment: Dans un cadre amical, c’est le mot *projet* qui vient en premier : « J’hésite à te [***re***]voir car la dernière fois qu’on s’est vus, tu as changé brutalement notre ***projet*** de rencontre amicale au dernier moment …… tu m'as laissé en plan, ce que je ne veux pas revivre ! »

Comment: J’hésite à te voir car la dernière fois que nous nous sommes vus tu as brusquement changé comment notre rencontre allait ou devait se dérouler . Je trouve rencontre amicale un peu fort pour des gens qui se tutoient.....planning, projet et programme me semble un peu trop ici.

Comment: @Lambie Peut-être que mon problème est d’axer à outrance mon attention sur la recherche de noms pour donner la description d’une situation donnée: si je me reporte à votre énonciation, on voit qu’ajouter quelques mots de plus à une formulation permet de dépeindre aisément sans trop se torturer l’esprit.

Comment: Mon problème semble se situer à ce niveau: l’agencement de mots permettant de donner corps à ma pensée ou de décrire un ressenti ou une émotion avec clarté et précision.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I**

Quelle que soit la phrase finale, je n'utiliserais aucun des mots « planning », « programme » et « plan » (et « projet »). La raison en est simple : ils dénotent tous des procédures plus ou moins formelles, plus ou moins fournies en directives strictes ; ce n'est pas le cas d'un arrangement dans le but d'une rencontre ; en fait on ne parlerait « d'organiser » le même type de rencontre que s'il s'agissait de la rencontre d'un groupe assez important, et même le verbe « arranger »  ne convient pas ; un tel évènement est plutôt quelque chose dont on « convient », pas seulement lorsqu'entre personnes qui se considèrent d'une façon plus ou moins distante, mais aussi entre amis, même si la démarche qui mêne à une telle rencontre n'est pas aussi formelle. Puisque le changement n'a d'incidence que sur une partie du temps que la rencontre devait durer on pourrait penser au mot « déroulement », mais celui-là ne convient pas non plus. Il semblerait qu'aucun mot n'existe qui soit propre à caractériser cette sorte d'arrangement, et donc il est préférable d'aborder le problème différemment. Puisqu'il existait une entente mutuelle à propos d'une rencontre des *prévisions* (« p. ext. » ci-dessous) avaient été faites.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9vision))  C. − Étude générale d'une situation donnée, dont on peut, par déduction, calcul, mesure scientifique, connaître par avance l'évolution;
> p.ext., ce que l'on prévoit, ce qui est prévisible, ce que l'on juge devoir être.

- J’hésite à te voir car la dernière fois qu’on s’est vus, tu as changé brutalement nos prévisions  de rencontre …

**II**  • *…mais on en est restés là, sous prétexte que la fatigue te gagnait.*

De la façon dont cette phrase est tournée on impute l'invocation d'un prétexte à « on », c'est à dire à « nous », la personne qui a recours au prétexte et celle qui s'en plaint.

- … mais tu en es resté là et j'en suis resté là sous prétexte que la fatigue te gagnait.

Il est préférable qu'un lien explicite soit formulé.

- … mais sous prétexte que la fatigue te gagnait tu m'a réduit a en rester là.

**III** *en rester là*

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rester)) **e)** **En rester à, en être resté à**
> − **S'arrêter, s'être arrêté dans un processus, une action en cours.**
> ♦︎ Freud en était resté aux identifications privées et c'est pourquoi il ne pouvait rejoindre la sociologie (Traité sociol., 1968, p. 410)
> ♦︎ Il faudra sans doute bien du temps avant que la vérité soit connue sur ce mystère de l'astrologie. En attendant qu'il soit levé − et rien ne nous empêche d'en rester sur ce point à une hypothèse de travail − la théorie symboliste fait apparaître une lumière nouvelle sur le plan de la pratique astrologique... Barbault, De psychanal. à astrol., 1961, p. 27.
> ♦︎ **En rester là** (de qqc.);
> ♦︎ restons-en là. Eugénie, ne comprenant plus rien à la fortune de son père, en resta là de ses calculs (Balzac, E. Grandet, 1834, p. 113).
> ♦︎ Tout ce que je vous en dis n'est que pour vous servir. Mais je vois que je vous contrarie. Restons-en là et quittons-nous bons amis (A. France, Jocaste, 1879, p. 103).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/processus)) **1.** Suite continue de faits, de phénomènes présentant une certaine unité ou une certaine régularité dans leur déroulement.

Il n'existe pas dans cette situation un processus, c'est à dire une suite continue de faits présentant une unité ; il n'existe pas non plus une action, où elle a très peu du nom d'une action puisqu'il n'est question que de rester ensemble. Cela rend l'expression « en rester là » peu pertinente.  Il me semble préférable de se débarrasser de cette expression au profit de quelque chose de plus explicite.

- … mais sous prétexte que la fatigue te gagnait tu m'as faussé compagnie.

**IV** *À mon sens, tu m’as laissé en plan et c’est fort impoli.*

Une raison valide justifie l'écourtement, même si on n'y croit pas du tout, et il n'y a pas d'impolitesse que l'on puisse mentionner, ni même de comportement rude dont on puisse se plaindre ; au contraire, on constate un effort dans le sens de ne pas blesser, le recours souvent pénible au mensonge de sorte à épargner de mauvais sentiments à quelqu'un, bien qu'il puisse exister la motivation plus ou moins grande de s'éviter des discussions épineuses. Donc, parler d'impolitesse ne serait pas approprié ou bien un moyen d'essayer de culpabiliser l'interlocuteur. Plus probable dans un tel contexte, le désappointement du locuteur est ce qui a le plus de pertinence.

- À mon sens, tu m’as laissé en plan et c’est fort décevant.

**V** Une reformulation sur le seul plan de la propriété des termes

- J’hésite à te voir car la dernière fois qu’on s’est vus, tu as changé brutalement nos prévisions  de rencontre amicale au dernier moment: on devait se rendre chez toi au sortir du restaurant mais sous prétexte que la fatigue te gagnait tu m'as faussé compagnie. À mon sens, tu m’as laissé en plan et c’est fort décevant.

**VI** Élimination de rappels qui peuvent paraitre inutiles

- J’hésite à te voir car la dernière fois qu’on s’est vus, tu as changé brutalement avant sa fin nos prévisions de passer la soirée ensemble : sous prétexte que la fatigue te gagnait tu m'as faussé compagnie. À mon sens, tu m’as laissé en plan et c’est fort décevant.

Comment: Bien honnêtement, j’aime la profondeur de vos analyses! Vous avez l’esprit fort pénétrant, LPH. C’est tout à votre mérite.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette C'est une idée satisfaisante de savoir que sur certains points nos pensées/opinions coïncides.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette À propos de votre correction : L'usage de « en » n'est pas faux, mais se passer de ce pronom dans le présent contexte grammatical me semble aussi correct. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22la%20raison%20est%20simple%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

Comment: Je suis d’accord avec vous sur ce point.

Answer (score 1):

Je suis perplexe devant le mélange de styles soutenu (par exemple, *notre rencontre amicale*) et familier (par exemple, l'usage répété de *on*).

Cela dit, le mot que j'entends le plus souvent dans ce genre de contexte, c'est-à-dire une sortie entre amis, est **plan** (par exemple: *le plan est de se retrouver au café, ensuite on ira au ciné*, ou bien: *tu as changé de plan au dernier moment*).

Dans un style strictement soutenu, j'utiliserais plutôt **programme** ou **agenda**.

Comment: Oui, le mélange de styles soutenu et familier.  Sutout signalé le par tutoiement.

Comment: correction: surtout :)

Comment: Effectivement Lambie! M’exprimer exactement en termes choisis n’est pas ma tasse de thé, parfois je me prends à me demander si j’aurais pu être atteint d’une dépersonnalisation: j’ai l’impression que mon dictionnaire mental a subi une désagrégation avec le temps.

Comment: J’attends l’avis d’un expert en psychiatrie ou en psychologie.